# Delay sending email by x seconds in Mail.app

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

Gmail has a useful feature where they allow you to "undo" the sending of an email by up to 30 seconds (if I recall correctly) of any email. It does this by not sending the email for up to 30 seconds, allowing you to cancel and edit the email, or not send it at all instead.

In using Mail.app on macOS, I've missed this incredibly useful feature. Is there a way to automatically send the email after, say, 30 seconds with the ability to cancel it before it's sent? Mail.app can use plugins, so maybe there's a plugin for this?

Note: I am looking more for a "send after delay" rather than a "schedule send" feature, which is more streamlined and allows me to send emails normally without having to choose a time.

Comment: Forget the Mail App from Apple.  The Outlook client - both web and on-prem has had this feature for some time now - both send with delay and send on schedule.  There are hardly any “built in” Apps that I use from Apple because they are simply lacking.  It seems they spent all their time on  Grapher (an awesome mathematical graphing utility) and just threw together Mail.  Seems they have their marketing utilization numbers backwards.

Comment: … or you could just read it more carefully before hitting Send…

Comment: or leave the recipient out until after you've triple checked it. Doing this will prevent the mail from being sent even if you hit the send button.

Comment: Great suggestions, fellas